# django haystack with elasticsearch - Searchqueryset not found

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I've implemented search in my django project with haystack and elastic search.

But searching with with a string across a Model that has a GenericForeignKey.

For the model I've used index_queryset in search index that filters w.r.t to a field.And the rebuild index can be seen indexing only the filtered count.
But when search happens the Haystack queryset shows:

> Object could not be found in database for SearchResult SearchResult: xxxxx.xxxxxx (pk=u'218933')

The above mentioned id was not actually indexed.But haystack has it in it's query.

```
django==1.10
haystack =2.6
aws elasticsearch == 2.3
```

With reference to https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/932, this can be a case of nodes being out of sync.

Will this arise in aws elasticsearch.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running `update_index` with the `--remove` flag?

Comment: I have a cron job running every 3 minutes for update_index.Command().handle(remove=True, age=settings.UPDATE_INDEX_AGE_HOURS)